# If term in file 1 is in line of file 2, write the whole line in file 2 to file 3

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a two text files, one containing a list of identifiers, the other containing a list of even more identifiers, plus some other bits of info I want.  What I want to do is compare the identifiers in files 1 and 2, and if they match, write the line in file 2 to a new file, file 3.

Here's what I have (it's a bit weird, as I got into lists and I never got that far in programming):

```
def identify(MOPED_Prot, Swiss_Prot, MOPED_to_Swiss):
  Swiss = open(Swiss_Prot, 'r') 
  M = open(M_Prot, 'r')
  output = open(M_to_Swiss, 'wt')
  Swissids = []
  ids = []
  for line in M.readlines():
    ids.append(line[:5])
  for line in Swiss.readlines():
    Swissids.append(line)
  while set(ids)& set(Swissids):
      output.write(#line?  Not sure what goes here + "\n")
```

I did get the code to write one of the lines from "Swiss" into the new file for every intersection with code similar to this, but it only repeated a single line.  Honestly, the end is what has me confused.

Edit:  As requested, here's what the files look like

File 1:

```
B4E035      
P23946      
O00376      
D6RGF3      
B2RDK6      
Q12999      
Q8TDD2      
B2RDC9      
C9JL66      
Q9NZQ9
```

File 2:

```
P31946  1433B_HUMAN YWHAB
P62258  1433E_HUMAN YWHAE
Q04917  1433F_HUMAN YWHAH YWHA1
P61981  1433G_HUMAN YWHAG
P31947  1433S_HUMAN SFN HME1
```

File 3 should output the line in file two, if any of the identifiers in the first column match (they are all 6 characters in length)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your files look like and what you want the output to be? :)

Comment: Yup!  I added it to the post

Comment: I updated my answer to match your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that file1 contains one identifier per line, maybe you can use something like this:

```
with open (file1, 'r') as f: ids = [line.strip () for line in f]
with open (file2, 'r') as f:
    with open (file3, 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            if any (id in line for id in ids): g.write (line)
```

**Nota bene:** I do not have python2.7 installed (and until now I read that you needed python2.7). Maybe you need to do some adaption to port this code to py2.

**EDIT**: Taking into consideration your sample data, you can try this:

```
with open (file1, 'r') as f: ids = [line.strip () for line in f]
with open (file2, 'r') as f:
    with open (file3, 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            if any (line.startswith (id) for id in ids): g.write (line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I write something here thata could help you...I put into a folder three files

file_a.txt (contaning in each line  1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

file_b.txt (contaning in each line  4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

final_file.txt

and this i my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import Counter

file_a = open('file_a.txt', 'r')
file_b = open('file_b.txt', 'r')
final_file = open('final_file.txt', 'w')

ids = []

for line in file_a.readlines():
  ids.append(line)

print ids
c = Counter(ids)

for line in file_b.readlines():
  print line;
  print 'count' + str(c[line])
  if c[line] > 0:
    final_file.write(line);

file_b.close();
final_file.close();
file_a.close();
```

Comment: I doubt that this works, as your IDs have a trailing newline.

Comment: this is very simple to countor...i write this script as an example, just adapt

Comment: @Hyperboreus this is right now...

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import Counter
file_a = open('file_a.txt', 'r')
file_b = open('file_b.txt', 'r')
final_file = open('final_file.txt', 'w')

ids = []

for line in file_a.readlines():
  ids.append(int(line))

c = Counter(ids)

for line in file_b.readlines():
  count = c[int(line)]
  print 'for line ' + line + ' counts' + str(count)
  if count > 0:
    final_file.write(line);

file_b.close();
final_file.close();
file_a.close();